# $ is not a function although jQuery is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

Firebug says "$ is not a function" although jQuery is loaded (twice!) on this site:

http://www.magiskecirkel.no/

Can anybody tell me why? :-)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Helge. If you get answers that help you resolve the question, please remember to "Accept" one by clicking the large checkmark to the left of it. This confirms that the issue has been resolved. Thanks. :)

Comment: Will do, seems I have to wait for another 5 minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery is set to no conflict mode on that page:
`$wpbr = jQuery.noConflict();`, so it's not bound to the $ function but to $wpbr.

Comment: +1 Very good observation. May I ask how did you find this in all the sources and code of the page?

Comment: Yes, the code is a mess. Cleaning it up now. Thank you very much, FRotthowe!

Comment: I searched the source for jQuery.

Comment: In fact, the problem is still there although I removed the `$wpbr = jQuery.noConflict();` code!

Answer (score 3):

You're using wordpress, which I believe includes the prototype library.  Prototype overwrites the '$' function provided by jquery: http://elementdesignllc.com/2009/08/wordpress-jquery-is-not-a-function/

you might want to check out noconflict mode: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit which lets `jQuery` use the name `jQuery` instead of `$`, and perhaps you've got that turned on.